# Cordova resolvaLocalFileSystemUrl() cannot async for loop within

Tags: angularjs, cordova

Here is my list[]

```
$scope.getCategory = function(){
var newList = [];
var list = [ 
{
   Category: 'Souenir',
   Image: 'http://domain.com/souvenir.jpg'
},
{
   Category: 'specialsouvenir',
   Image: 'http://domain.com/specialsouvenir.jpg'
},
{
   Category: 'flower',
   Image: 'http://domain.com/flower.jpg'
},
{
   Category: 'Toy',
   Image: 'http://domain.com/toy.jpg'
}];

for(var i = 0;i < list.length;i++){
        var item = list[i];
        var category = '';
        var image = '';
        var imageName = item.Image.split("/").pop();
        var path = '';
        path = 'cdvfile://localhost/persistent/';
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path+imageName, function(entry) {
            image = entry.toURL();
             newList.push({Category:item.Category,Image:image});
        });
    }

    return newList;
}
```

The result show:

4 items [**correct**]

images for each item[**correct**]

BUT Category show  the last loop item instead in each 4 items [**error**] 
[image]
Here is the screenshot for iPad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a classic JS trap. Since you pushing items to `newList` in `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL` callback, which is asynchronous, you have access only to the last item from the `for` loop, which is synchronous.

So the JS event loop will look something like this:
1 for > 2 for > 3 for > 4 for > 1 callback > 2 callback > 3 callback > 4 callback

There is a great [video](https://vimeo.com/96425312) explaining it.

To solve your problem and have a unique category for each item, you should wrap async operation in self-called function. Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/409ahfz8/) explaining it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir, I kinda knows how it works now but is there a way to make it return to a list after the operation?

Comment: cos this return method seems return null before the push()                                                                               `getCategory: function(){                                                                            for(){<asynctask>}                                                                                        return list;                                                                                                            }`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @antonama answer!

```
for(var i = 0;i < list.length;i++){

   (function (i) {
          var item = CategoryList[i];
          var image = '';
          var imageName = CategoryList[i].Image.split("/").pop();
          var path = '';
          path = 'cdvfile://localhost/persistent/';
          window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path+imageName, function(entry) {
            image = entry.toURL();
            list.push({Category:item.Category,Image:image});
        });
      })(i);
}
```

After the async operation, I add a setTimeout() to refresh and return the list or else the list return will be empty.

```
setTimeout(function(){
   list = list;
});
return list;
```

Then Done!