# Calling resolveLocalFileSystemURL within a loop

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap

I have an array that contains file names. My code needs to check each file to find out if it needs to be downloaded or it it already exists. The problem is that when I call the resolveLocalFileSystemURL function from the loop, is does not get the correct file name, it always gets the last file name from the array. Any suggestions how to pass the correct file name along with the function call?

```
var currentFile = "";
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) 
{
    currentFile = files[i];
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory + currentFile , ok, downloadFile);
}

function downloadFile() {
....download currentFile....
}

function ok(entry)
{
...
}
```

Comment: Your code seems correct to me, can you put a debugger and inspect the contents of the array?

Comment: Use the promise because loop doesn't wait for the result of the called function. Because in the loop that function is called again and again that's why it show the last function result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I managed to solve it (reference: [Cordova resolvaLocalFileSystemUrl() cannot async for loop within](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41309646/cordova-resolvalocalfilesystemurl-cannot-async-for-loop-within/41315126))

```
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) 
    {
        (function (i) {
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory + files[i]
        , function(entry){  
           ...ok....    
        }
        , function() {
           ...download files[i]...
        });
     })(i);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.prototype.map and new Promise to convert files into an array of promises and Promise.all to convert all promises to one promise that will resolve in all values or reject on first error.

```
Promise.all(
  files.map(
    function(file){
      return new Promise(
        function(resolve,reject){
          window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
            cordova.file.dataDirectory + currentFile,
            function(file){
              resolve(file)
            },
            function(){
              //download file (maybe as promise and return that)
              return downloadFile(file);
            }
          );
        }
      )
    }
  )
).then(
  function(files){
    console.log("ok",files);
  }
)
.catch(
  function(error){
    console.log("error:",error);
  }
);
```

Comment: Is it possible to keep the loop?

Comment: @user2763405 not sure why you would want to do that but you can write declarative code by creating an array and push to that array in the loop then use that array for Promise.all. I'd stick with imperative code though. I'm using the archaic `function` since you use cordova (web view) and not use babel (judging by the code provided which looks dated). You could simplify the code a lot with arrow functions.

Comment: Thank you, I wanted a simple fix since i am not familiar with Promise. Does adding a property to the function call work?